# VK API Как сделать большой запрос?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как к API ВК Отправить большой запрос. Вот пример простого кода API который я использую. Но мне кажется что делать это в цикле как то не правильно, есть ли другой способ для API ВКонтакте чтобы была возможность отправлять один большой запрос?

```html
// $array большой массив с даннымы

foreach($array as $value){

    $request_params = [
        'owner_id' => $value["owner_id"],
        'post_id' => $value["post_id"],
        'access_token' => $value["user_token"]
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.delete');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query($request_params).'&v=6.76');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $wallDelete = curl_exec($ch);
    $wallDelete = json_decode($wallDelete,true);
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: Что под вашим понимание большой запрос? Такого термина нет.

Comment: @And массив $array более 1000 запросов если в foreach делать получится к серверу ВК, а у них там ограничение. Но решение уже нашел, метод execute помогает решить этот вопрос.

Comment: Ну дак, задержки же нужно делать, а не крутить цикл.

Comment: @And sleep(time) так и раньше делал, но обрабатывалось все очень долго. Благодаря методу execute ускорил этот процес. Плохо только что в этом методе можно использовать только один токен пользователя для задачи с его аккаунтом.

Comment: Чем вас крон не устраевает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [execute](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=execute) может содержать до 25 обращений к методам API ВКонтакте.